# Should the tags "sync" and "synchronize" be synonymized?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I asked in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and there was unanimous agreement, but none of the present had the permissions to even suggest a tag synonym, since the requirements are a rep of over 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag (which I find a little restrictive, but anyway, that's beside the point). Could someone powerful enough do that (assuming there's no objection)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm onboard... But which way? [sync](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sync) has 449 posts and [synchronize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/synchronize) only has 91.

I'm going to munge things down to "sync" for now because it seems people are naturally lazy.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention the consensus was to have "sync" be the canonical one.